# Joining tables with dates IN SQL

Tags: sql, join, teradata

[spread-sheet rendering of two tables given and view wanted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpAKP.png)

How I can JOIN these tables in SQL to have that view?
I have a lot of products.

I TRIED TO JOIN PRODUCT THEN DATE BETWEEN START_DATE AND END_DATE and it's not working.
How I can do this?

Comment: Can you show the SQL code that you have tried

Comment: Hi - please don't link to images, use editable text. Update your question to show the source table definition(s), sample data, the result you want to achieve and the SQL you've manged to wrote on your own - and then explain precisely what the issue is that you are facing (is the result wrong, are you getting an error message, etc.)

Comment: If you actually use DATE it's a keyword returning the same as CURRENT_DATE, i.e. today

Answer (score 1):

Using subquery is a better way to address this scenario since you need a ranged output.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
WHERE
    table1.data BETWEEN (SELECT data_start FROM table2) AND (SELECT data_end FROM table2)
```

Its output matches your expected output.

Here's the [Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/077N846e)

And make sure there's only 1 record in table2 so that query can pick exactly one start and end date, otherwise, use `MAX` with the values in the `BETWEEN` subqueries.